# Creating a flip content with the content sliding in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently learning javascript and I would like to make sliding different div containers along with flipping the contents inside each sliding div container when you click the container that is sliding.

I have created a content sliding div by following the example shown in  [gliding content](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/featuredcontentglider.htm) and i have also got an example for fliping the content using the  link provided in [flipping content](http://dev.jonraasch.com/quickflip/examples/).  I have integrated both of them but the flipping of the content doesn't seem to work, when I try to do them separately it works fine.

Any help regarding this would be grateful,

Thanks

**EDIT*****
I have no idea how to use jsfiddle but some how have done this ,as i have no idea how to make folders in js fiddle and place my files ,  javascript and css  has no reference to source files  , any help regarding this would  be grateful
The basic idea is as shown in my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/samantha/jLjPJ/1/) ,

Comment: show your code and if possible show the exact problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You wrote that you've created an example, might be helpful to post that code.

Comment: Regarding jsFiddle. First: Scale the code down to what the problem evolves about. If it's coderelated, CSS isn't needed to solve the problem. If you are using a framework (like you are) you can include it in the left menu by selecting it. You were using jQuery 1.3.2 which is quite old but can probably use a newer version. All of the other javascript can be added if needed by using the "Add Resource" to the left and linking them into the document. One of the issues in your code is that you have three separate calls to a jquery javascript file. One is always enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do custom stuff, it might be best to learn CSS3 rather than trying to use plugins.  MDN has excellent articles on CSS3 [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) (animations) and [transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) (for flip, it's 3D rotations that you want).

Here's a demo with some simultaneous sliding/flipping (Webkit only; you have to add the other vendor prefixes to make it work on Firefox, IE, etc).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hwtt/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1/" />
    <img class="slider" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/2/" />
</div>

<input value="flip" id="flip" type="button" />
<input value="slide" id="slide" type="button" />
<input value="both" id="both" type="button" />
```

**CSS**

```
.container { 
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
  margin-top: -200px;  
}
.flip {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
}
img {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
}
div {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

​
**JS**

```
var stop = false;
$(".container").each(function(i,e) {
    e.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function(e) {
    if (stop === false) {
        $(this).toggleClass("flip");    
        stop = true;
    }
    });
});

function flip(e) { 
    stop = false;
    $(".container").toggleClass("flip"); 
}
function slide() { 
    $(".slider").toggleClass("slide"); 
}
function both() {
    flip();
    slide();
}

$(document).on("click", ".container", function() {
    flip.call(this);
    slide(this);
});

$("#flip").click(flip);
$("#slide").click(slide);
$("#both").click(both);
```

​